# DataGridViewColumn properties not propagating down to control

Tags: winforms, datagridviewcolumn

I'm am working through an example over at the MSDN website for [Hosting custom controls within the datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28VS.80%29.aspx). The Problem that I am running into is that I have a Property on the DataGridviewColumn that can be set at design time but it is not getting passed down to individual cells in the column.

```
public class CalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public string MyCoolNewProperty {get;set;}

    public CalendarColumn() : base(new CalendarCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null && 
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        CalendarColumn obj = (CalendarColumn)base.Clone();
        obj.MyCoolNewProperty = this.MyCoolNewProperty ;
        return obj;
    }
}



   public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
public string MyCoolNewProperty {get;set;}
    public CalendarCell()
        : base()
    {
        // Use the short date format.
        this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object 
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, 
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CalendarEditingControl ctl = 
            DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
        ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing contol that CalendarCell uses.
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value.
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        CalendarCell obj = (CalendarCell)base.Clone();
        obj.MyCoolNewProperty = this.MyCoolNewProperty ;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

How can i get the properties to propagate down to the cells and then the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely overlooked the InitializeEditingControl function within the CalendarCell class which gets called when the cell is created. From here I added the one line needed to access the properties of the column it belongs to.

```
   public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
public string MyCoolNewProperty {get;set;}
    public CalendarCell()
        : base()
    {
        // Use the short date format.
        this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object 
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, 
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CalendarEditingControl ctl = 
            DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
        ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
        // Access any Column Properties
        ctl.MyCoolNewProperty = ((CalendarColumn)base.OwningColumn).MyCoolNewProperty; 
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing contol that CalendarCell uses.
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value.
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        CalendarCell obj = (CalendarCell)base.Clone();
        obj.MyCoolNewProperty = this.MyCoolNewProperty ;
        return obj;
    }
}
```